Запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме
OC ubunto
Через консоль, запускаю пайтон скрипт. В скрипте команда ffmpeg, преобразование видео длится около пары часов.
Если закрою консоль, выполнение процесса прервется.
Как через консоль, запустить скрипт в фоне?
Знаю id процесса, ffmpeg отдает в консоль прогресс преобразования видео. Если ранее скрипт был запущен в фоне, зная id процесса. Возможно открыть в консоле ход выполнения преобразования видео?

Вам нужно воспользоваться командой screen
Запускаете терминал, запускаете screen, будет внешне ничем не отличающийся терминал. В нем запускаете вашу программу. Но при зарытии терминала со скрином команда не завершается.
Командой screen -list увидите список открытых скринов.
Вернуться к какомуто из них можно командой screen -r 34.pts-1.erix где 34.pts-1.erix это айдишник из списка.

В данный момент не возможности проверить. После того как вернулись к запущенному скрипту и закрыли консоль, скрипт перестанет выполнятся в фоне или же необходимо удалить его командой из списка?

Он выполняется пока его насильно не завершит система или пользователь. Консоль посылает HUP при закрытии, но скрин сессию сохраняет живой
